# Cannot get values from Gridview when binding it without SQLDatasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am binding some Data in the Page_load method in GridView1. I have a checkBox CheckBox1. After checking the checkboxes i want to display something(As a test) in the Label1 when i press a button . But it is not showing. I am not Binding Data with SQLDatasource rather i am binding it manually.

My Page_load method

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string[,] arrMultiD = {
                { "John", "21", "Berlin", "Germany" },
                { "Smith", "33" ,"London", "UK"},
                { "Ryder", "15" ,"Sydney", "Australia"},
                { "Jake", "18", "Tokyo", "Japan"},
                { "Tom","34" , "Mumbai", "India"}
             };
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("City", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Country", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Name"] = arrMultiD[i, 0];
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Age"] = arrMultiD[i, 1];
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["City"] = arrMultiD[i, 2];
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Country"] = arrMultiD[i, 3];
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

My Button Click function

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        // Access the CheckBox
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            Label1.Text += "1";
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked in debug mode. When i was clicking the button, the if portion was not being executed. It is as if the Data in the GridView was lost as soon as i clicked the button. In other words GridView lost its data when it was out of Page_Load method

my aspx code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="dd">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you check in debug mode if you enter into **Button1_Click** and the **if** inside it?

Comment: Yes I checked with Debug mode. It does not Enter into the if portion. Its as if the Gridview has no data inside it when i click the button.

Comment: Amit Tiwari, It does not work. :(

Comment: Can you put .aspx code of gridview and button

Comment: Can you post html for your GridView?

Comment: Mandar Patil i have edited the post. Please see.

Comment: And is cb null or unchecked in the if statement?

Comment: i am clicking the checkboxes. it remains false. Not null.

Comment: Then test !IsPostBack before initializing in the page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you have to check for IsPostBack on page load before binding the grid.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string[,] arrMultiD = {
            { "John", "21", "Berlin", "Germany" },
            { "Smith", "33" ,"London", "UK"},
            { "Ryder", "15" ,"Sydney", "Australia"},
            { "Jake", "18", "Tokyo", "Japan"},
            { "Tom","34" , "Mumbai", "India"}
         };
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("City", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Country", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Name"] = arrMultiD[i, 0];
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Age"] = arrMultiD[i, 1];
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["City"] = arrMultiD[i, 2];
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Country"] = arrMultiD[i, 3];
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        // Access the CheckBox
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            Label1.Text += "1";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string[,] arrMultiD = {
        { "John", "21", "Berlin", "Germany" },
        { "Smith", "33" ,"London", "UK"},
        { "Ryder", "15" ,"Sydney", "Australia"},
        { "Jake", "18", "Tokyo", "Japan"},
        { "Tom","34" , "Mumbai", "India"}
     };
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Age", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("City", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Country", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Name"] = arrMultiD[i, 0];
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Age"] = arrMultiD[i, 1];
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["City"] = arrMultiD[i, 2];
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Country"] = arrMultiD[i, 3];
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

place your code in page.ispostbak block

Comment: check now the solution you have not implemented the condition for postback hence on button click it reload the page and clear the checkbox...